# Pound sign in VFP not showing on specific PC, all other PCs are OK

Tags: visual-foxpro

My issue is as follows :

All PCs show the pound sign correctly within VFP, except one PC.

On the offending PC, the pound sign works fine in all programs (Word\Notepad\Email client\etc....) except in our VFP app it is shown as a square (or unrecognized character), but if I go to our VFP app on any other PC on the network and view the exact same record\data it is shown correctly as a pound sign.

I have checked the codepage is set to Ansii-1252 and I have checked the regional and keyboard settings within Windows (which are set to the UK).

We have 100's of users using different VFP apps and I've never seen this issue, so I'm a bit stumped.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Cheers, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the windows language settings for non unicode programs in Control Panel / Region / Administrative tab.